# Using SuiteScript to populate a transfer order

Tags: netsuite, populate, suitescript

Current issue is that i can't commit a line item. Do i need to add more fields even though item is the only one required?

```
function OLDcreateTO() //(request, response)
{
    for ( var i = 1; i < lines + 1 ; i++ )
    {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type,"line # " + i);
        arrayName[i] = PORecord.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', i ); 
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, arrayName[i]);
    }

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, lines + ' lines');


    var TOrecord = nlapiCreateRecord ('transferorder');
    var TOrecordID = TOrecord.getId();
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('customform',128);
    //subsidiaries CC bedford id is 2
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('subsidiary',2);
    //testing for location and transfer location, 144 & 145
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('location',144);
    TOrecord.setFieldValue('transferlocation',145);

    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, 'break 4');
    // add new lines to a sublist
    nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
    // set the item and location values on the currently selected line
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', arrayName[1]);
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'location', 6);
    // commit the line to the database
    nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, 'break 5');

    var TOResult = nlapiSubmitRecord(TOrecord, true, true);
    var TOTranID= nlapiLookupField('transferorder', TOResult, 'tranid');
     nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, 'break 6');
    var poURL = nlapiResolveURL('RECORD', 'transferorder', TOResult);

    nlapiSetRedirectURL('RECORD','transferorder', TOResult);


     }
```

So I am trying to have the items of a purchase order populate the items field on a new transfer order via a button on the PO. From there the user can make any changes they want to the record before submitting it and creating the TO. The main issue is I don't know how to populate a blank TO from script. I have it redirect there via a url string, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

In summary.

-User clicks "create TO" button on a PO

-takes user to the "create TO" page where all the items (and some various info) is pre populated depending on the PO.

-User edits the record and then submits it.

suitescript 1.0
    //create_to_button

```
var newId ;
var newType ;
function beforeload(type)
{
    if(nlapiGetContext().getRole() == '3')
    {
        if(type =='view' || type == 'edit')
        {
            newId = nlapiGetRecordId();
            newType = nlapiGetRecordType();

                if(newType == 'purchaseorder')
                {

                    var strURL = "https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/trnfrord.nl"
                    var scriptbutton = 'window.open(' + String.fromCharCode(39) + strURL + String.fromCharCode(39) + ')' ;
                    //nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, 'URL: '+strURL + '&id=' + newId);
                    form.addButton('custpage_createpo', 'Create TO', scriptbutton);

                }

        }
    }
}

function loadTO() //(request, response)
{
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','<Before Load Script> type: '+type, 'hello');
     nlapiLoadRecord(newType, newId);
}
```

Any ideas or advice is appreciated.
-Brandon

Answer (score 0):

If you know the TO will be saved you would open a Suitelet that will populate the TO. Save it and redirect to the new TO using nlapiSetRedirect with a url from nlapiResolveURL.

If the TO might not be saved then add some parameters to the tasklink url that you are already using and add your population logic to the TO's client side init function. You may need to add some custom fields to the TO with a beforeLoad user event script to provide the info the client script needs. (Your client script can look at query string parameters too but depending on what you are doing the server side lookups may be faster).

Comment: That makes sense. 
One weird issue im running into is that whatever script i have attached to the button, it will run that script on load without being clicked. But the whole purpose of the button is to only activate the script when clicked.

form.addButton('custpage_purchaseorder', 'Create TO', loadTO());

Would you have any idea why thats happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I think so. NS expects `"window.open('"+href +"')"` i.e use double quotes to create your script and single quotes to quote strings.

Comment: I'm a little confused. How would "window.open" help me run a function on button click?
It seems like i would have to have the entire script in "window.open" .
would the format be something like
`window.open("entire function " + 'function call')` ?

Comment: Ok, I think i got that part. 
`var steve = "alert(\'Button was clicked from \' + nlapiGetRecordType() + \' in VIEW mode\');";`
and then
`form.addButton('custpage_purchaseorder', 'Create TO', steve);`

Comment: The quotes are funny because of how they embed the button action.
You are actually expected to load a client script and use one of its exposed methods.

Comment: the last issue i'm having is my script erroring out and i'm not entirely sure why. I add a new item, set it and commit it and im still getting the error of "You must enter at least one line item for this transaction."
Script is in the main post.

Comment: You are using client side or dynamic mode api calls for server side/non-dynamic. `TOrecord.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', arrayName[1], 1);`